# SQL command not properly ended in fetch and union using

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Why this query return 'SQL command not properly ended' error?

```
select column1, length(column1) from test10 order by length(column1), column1 asc 
fetch first 1 rows only
union
select column1, length(column1) from test10 order by length(column1) desc, column1 asc fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database has problems to identify where what belongs.

so you can help the parser with parenthesis

> ```
> CREATE tABLE test10 (column1 varchar2(10))
> ```

> ```
> (select column1, length(column1) 
> from test10 
> order by length(column1), column1 asc 
> fetch first 1 rows only)
> union
> (select column1, length(column1) 
> from test10 
> order by length(column1) desc, column1 asc 
> fetch first 1 rows only);
> ```
>
> ```
> COLUMN1 | LENGTH(COLUMN1)
> :------ | --------------:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f121b9505ee4880b3838880e496f72c3)*

hackerrank has a really old engine

So the result to that problem is

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM
(SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) 
, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY  LENGTH(CITY) ASC,CITY ASC) rn
FROM STATION)
WHERE rn = 1
UNION
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM
(SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) 
, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY  LENGTH(CITY) DESC,CITY DESC) rn
FROM STATION)
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

Comment: actually, it is a Hackerrank problem. I tried code as you wrote but it worked on neither Hackerrank nor livesqloracle. I will change the query completely. But thank you for explaining why doesn't work query in question.

Comment: have you a link, as this should run every where

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-5/problem?isFullScreen=true

Comment: @deku If it's a HackerRank question then why have you tagged SQL Developer? What exactly did you try and what was the error? nbc's answer does resolve the syntax error in your question, so maybe you should either mark it as correct or supply more details.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I am new at StackOverflow and I'm not good at using it yet. So I didn't know there is a Hackerrank tag. But still, my problem was like that, and I think it is appropriate for the SQL developer tag.

Comment: There is no HackerRank tag. The [oracle-sqldeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle-sqldeveloper/info) tag is for questions about using the [Oracle SQL Developer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer/index.html) application, not for SQL in general.

Comment: @deku i took your test, and the version used doesn't support `fetch first 1 rows only`

Comment: @nbk Nice catch - running `select * from v$version` in HackerRank shows that "Oracle" means Oracle 11.2 XE from about ten years ago.